# Keyup text filter that ONLY filters on newly-typed text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a keyup function that filters div elements based on a `<textarea>'s` content. When the user finds the div they want, they can drag it into the textarea and its text gets added. So far it's working, but only when the user starts typing from an empty textarea. If content is already present in the textarea and the user wants to add more to it, the filter doesn't work because it tries to filter all the text. I would like to modify the function to only filter on newly-typed text. For instance if the textarea already contains "Some random text;" and the user starts typing after the semicolon "Some random text; (new text)", I only want it to filter on (new text). Is this possible?

My filter:

```
$(function () {
    $('#modalTextArea').keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val(),
        count = 0;
        $('#modalJobList div').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My div repeater being filtered:

```
<div id='modalJobList' class="board-list">
    <asp:Repeater ID="modalJobRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id='modalCardJob<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Job"))%>' class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" data-appendto="job">
                <p><%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Job")) + " - " + string.Format("{0}", Eval("Description"))%></p>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

My textarea:

```
<textarea id="modalTextArea" data-boxtype="modalText" ondrop="dropIt(event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the letters in an array as you type. then checking the current count of the array when typing and avoiding all letters previous to that. if that is possible